Lifted/desaturated blacks in Photoshop after calibration
For the past two weeks I've been trying to get Photoshop to work. Whenever I open a photograph into Photoshop the shadows are lifted and posterized.
It seems to be a monitor profile problem, but I can't seem to fix it. I use a Display SL from Calibrite, but have the same problem with Spyder X Pro and Spyder 5 Express.
I already switched up Photoshop versions, bought and returned three different monitors, two macs and two calibration tools to pinpoint where the problem lay.
At the moment I am trying to make it all work on a Mac Mini M2 Pro (Sonoma) and a BenQ SW240 Monitor with the Display SL tool through Calibrites own software.
In this screen capture you can see what happens when I choose my calibrated profile, also happens with the standard AdobeRGB1998 profile. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izYDPxoH-QM&themeRefresh=1
Hope somebody can help me out here! :)


Are you using 16-bit images? What type? What is your Colour Settings page set to in Ps?

Also using 16-bit Adobe RGB files. Color settings are default, changing anything in there didn't solve the problem. During calibration I used 2.2g and D65. Also tried different settings for the sake of troubleshooting, but to no avail.

Default is to translate imports… which is why I asked what your settings were - I guess a screenshot would help.

Thanks for replying, I added a screenshot in my post above!

Hmm… settings look fine, but even that screenshot is well washed-out - https://i.sstatic.net/H5Bey1Oy.png Do you have any of the 'fancy; display settings enabled - True Tone, auto-brightness, night shift etc?


what is the program which you are comparing the PS to? 2) did you verify by other means that there is indeed no posterization in the sample image? 3) what colour profile does sample image have?


You can try using the ColorSync utility to check/repair the installed profiles. If it doesn't find any issues with the problem profiles then is likely a setting selected during profiling... at least for your custom profile.
Make sure you are using standard 2.2 gamma during calibration; D65 is generally preferred as well..

I tried the ColorSync, but that didn't owrk. Also using 16-bit Adobe RGB files. Color settings are default, changing anything in there didn't solve the problem.
During calibration I used 2.2g and D65. Also tried different settings for the sake of troubleshooting, but to no avail.
A friend came over with his Mac M2 Studio and Spyder X Pro and monitor, but same problem. So now we tried three different screens, three different calibration tools and three different Mac M2's.

So we narrowed it down to either a PS bug or a M2 bug, could also be the two interacting as Photoshop has the same problem with the default Adobe RGB 1998 monitor setting; when switching IRL ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izYDPxoH-QM&themeRefresh=1 ) you can see PS uses the correct color display for a millisecond before crushing the shadows.

Does color sync show the right icc for the display's assigned profile? What happens if you change it in color sync?

I am afraid I am not completly sure what you mean. It does use the right path when I am checking it out in ColorSync Utility and the BenQ SW240 uses it as the current profile under the 'Devices' tab.

Have you tried turning off soft proofing?  If that's turned on Photoshop may be trying to show you your selected "printer" (profile) doesn't print very dark.  You might also try turning off the black-point compensation.

hey thanks for replying! Yep also checked that. Turning ff black-point compensation also didn't make any difference. I think I tried flipping every PS setting there is by now haha
I think it might be a GPU bug with the M2 and apple! As Adobe also mentioned in an email it might have to do with the M2 chips :(
